# Correct use of symbols in several dependent probabilities?

Tags: probability

To use a task as an example: If you draw $5$ cards from a deck, show the probability that everyone is spades:

$P(S)=\frac{13}{52}$

$$P(S\cap S \cap S...)=P(S)\cdot P(S|S) \cdot P(S|S|S)…?$$

My book just says $P({\rm all\; spades})= \frac{13}{52}\cdot \frac{12}{51}...$

Comment: Aside from using the same symbol for different events (*don't do that*), there is *never more than one partitioner* ("$\mid$") in a conditional measure function, with the event to its left and the conditions to its right. It is not a set operator; it makes no sense to use more than one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have events $S_k$...k-th card is spade. So you are interested in $$P(S_1\cap S_2\cap S_3\cap S_4\cap S_5) = $$ $$=P(S_1)\cdot P(S_2|S_1)\cdot P(S_3|S_1\cap S_2)\cdot P(S_4|S_1\cap S_2\cap S_3)\cdot P(S_5|S_1\cap S_2\cap S_3\cap S_4)$$
$$ = {13\over 52}\cdot {12\over 51}\cdot {11\over 50}\cdot {10\over 49}\cdot {9\over 48}$$